# Not able to send the image to node.js api through postman

Tags: node.js, api, postman

I am trying to use the postman for debug the api calls.
For that I need to upload the video which will be upload to server using the node.js.

I am trying to send the video data to form-data as type selected file and on console I check on request body and it showing undefined. If I send the key value like some string then that string is fetched and show but not in case of video.

I am attaching the image so that it will through some lights to the error I am facing.

[image]

Is there anyone who suggest me why I am getting the media field as undefined and what is the solution for getting the data.
Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you reading the form-data in the API? Are you using `multer` or `formidable`? Can you share the API endpoint code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [express-fileupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload).
This is a middleware you use with Express.js

```
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')

app.use(fileUpload({
     limits: { fileSize: 50 * 1024 * 1024 },
}));
```